# reverse tunnel with Windows

Tags: reverse, tunnel

PC_A is behind NAT/Firewall, it runs Windows. 
PC_B is Debian server with public IP and with OpenSSH. 
I want to access files on PC_A from any PC_C.

On PC_A I execute this:

```
plink.exe -R 12345:localhost:22 root@PC_B
```

From PC_B I run:

```
ssh -p 12345 localhost
```

plink.exe supports reverse tunneling, but does would it work without openssh server?

Answer (score 0):

solved. Needed to install SSH server on PC_A (win7). plink.exe is just a client.